# What is the reference for High side IC with internal mosfet driver

Tags: power-supply, power, analog

In the schematic below (like many other) the IC (switcher) is on the high side.
I was really curious how the internal circuitry of such an IC is referenced to.

My first thought was that everything is referenced to the source. Because my reasoning was that internally there is a N-channel MOSFET, so you would want to drive referenced to the source. 
What contradicts this reasoning is that the source is a switching node.

But if they use the drain as reference, then how do they sense and drive etc

**My question is not specific for this IC, but in general for high side switchers.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the circuitry is referenced to the source of the power MOSFET. In this particular case there may be nothing referenced to ground but usually there is (control input for high side driver, for example). There needs to be level translation between the two.

You can see this if you read the datasheet for the LTYswitch:
[image]

For a high side bootstrap driver you can see the level translation circuitry as in the below diagram extracted from the datasheet for the [IRS2110](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers_AN978-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f7cf21200):

[image]

Neither one of these datasheets is all that clear on where the references are for the high side drivers etc., unfortunately.

Comment: The 5.8V mentioned is that reference to the source or drain?

Comment: Reference to the source.

Comment: I do understand the IC's such IRS2110 which are referenced to ground combined with level shifting. But this is a bit different it seems .